# Azure AD Client Credential refresh the access token

Tags: adal

I am developing Daemon (App-Only or Unattended) service to communicate with office 365 using EWS, to do this I have acquired a toke using following code.

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxCertificateFilePath, pfxPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
ClientAssertionCertificate cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new 
AuthenticationContext(authApiUri);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceServerName, cac);
authenticationResult.AccessToken;
```

I am looking for an option to refresh the access token. 
I got chance to look at the [wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) given by #adal team unfortunately I am confused with the following statement

> Note that, AcquireTokenSilent does not need to be called in the Client credentials flow (when the application acquires token without a user, but in its own name)"

Please clarify how to refresh the token obtained by `ClientAssertionCertificate`.

Thanks
Mahendran

Comment: I think it means that you refresh via application credentials instead. Have you checked this link? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7498ae67-8163-4d81-9430-21165758b8d7/adal-failed-to-acquire-token-silently-issue?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: Hi Marilee,
 Thanks for your quick response, the given link describing more about the multi tenant problem. Could please point me the exact place look in to it.
I have tried below code to refresh the token it throws error "Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"
 
cac = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, cert);
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authApiUri);
authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceServerName, cac, UserIdentifier.AnyUser);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Please clarify how to refresh the token obtained by ClientAssertionCertificate.

Unfortunately, there is **no refresh token** returned by using clientAssertionCertificate. We could capture the request with fiddler.

[image]

Comment: Tom,
 I experience the same, there is no refresh token. So what it means the access token got with ClientAssertionCertificate will not expire soon. Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: @MahendranP  `So what it means the access token got with ClientAssertionCertificate will not expire soon`. When we use the ClientAssertionCerticate to get accesstoken. It also need the client_assertion token. And the azure SDK generate the token for us it including the expired time. We also could generate it by ourself. For more information about client_assertion  way to get accesstoken, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/TomSunGit/AzureADDemo#use-client-assertion-to-get-access-tokens-from-azure-ad).

Comment: When I tried the following code authenticationResult.ExpiresOn.UtcDateTime , it always expire in 1 hour. I couldn't figure how to refresh the token after 1 hour. Please help me to refresh the token.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't return  refresh token. So we can't get the refresh token, In your case, you could store the token somewhere and record the get expiration  time, before that time and get token again to replace the older token. Or As I mentioned that we could generate  the client_assertion by ourselves. And we could custom expiration time by ourself. For more information, please refer to this [link](https://github.com/TomSunGit/AzureADDemo#use-client-assertion-to-get-access-tokens-from-azure-ad).

Comment: Thanks Tom for your time, I cleared the cache and then acquired the token again it gave me new token.
 //clear the cached token , this allows the AcquireTokenAsync method call the server to get new token.
authenticationContext.TokenCache.Clear();